# Branding InstallShield 2010

Tags: installshield, installscript-msi

I have created a basic MSI project using InstallShield2010. Now, I want the same project for building setup of different brands. Each brand have some information different from another like product name, guid etc. 
Is it possible to that while building project I can provide a file path from where InstallShield can pick these parameters?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to utilize the InstallShield Automation Interface:

> For advanced developers, InstallShield exposes a COM interface that
>   allows you to perform many of the same tasks from a program, such as a
>   Visual Basic executable, or a script, such as a VBScript file in
>   Windows Scripting Host. By calling methods, setting properties,
>   accessing collections, and so on, through the automation interface,
>   you can open a project and modify its features and component data in
>   many of the same ways that you would in the InstallShield interface.

With this "Automation Interface", you can write your build script to dynamically change the variables you're interested in (e.g. product name, guid, etc.) while building each version of your installer.

See:  [Automation Interface](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/IHelpAutomation.htm)